# How can I make this inverted scrolling script work more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling, onscroll

The webpage I'm designing is very tall and loads in at the bottom. I need the scrolling to be inverted so visitors won't have to scroll up to get to the top. The script I'm using doesn't fully prevent normal scrolling and causes some issues:

```
function onScroll(velocity) {
  var win = $(window)  
  $(win).on('wheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var direction = event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0? 'down': 'up';    
    var position = win.scrollTop();

    if (direction === 'up') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (position + velocity)
        }, 40);
    }
    else if (direction === 'down') {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (position - velocity)
        }, 40);
    }
  })
}
onScroll(70);
```

What adjustments could be made to the script to streamline the process?

Comment: Why do you use `40ms` animations? Why don't you use `scrollTo()` or `scrollBy()` native JS methods instead? What's that you're building? What is the issue you're facing? What do you mean by: *"normal scrolling"*? PS, one can always grab the scrollbar and move it around... and then what?

Comment: Why you named velocity something that is actually just a scrroll offset, step px distance? –

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This was not originally my code, I am just trying to improve on it with very little knowledge. The issue I'm facing is that instead of inverting the scroll from top-bottom to bottom-top (my intention), scrolling seems to randomly switch between the two. I'm trying to build a website with a skyscraper background that starts at the bottom, and I want the scrolling to be inverted so it can be user-friendly and less confusing than having to scroll up from the base to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need jQuery.
Here's an example using pure JavaScript to invert the "wheel" scroll direction:

```js
const elScroll = document.documentElement;

elScroll.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {

  evt.preventDefault();
  const delta = Math.sign(-evt.deltaY);
  
  elScroll.scrollBy({
    top: 70 * delta,
    // behavior: "smooth" // will not work I'm afraid
  });
  
}, { passive: false });
```

```css
body {
  border: 3px dashed;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
Wheel-up to scroll down, and vice-versa
```

Sadly the option `behavior: "smooth"` will not work correctly with the above. For animations to work you'll have to find another workaround.